# Get all column names on a ARRAY in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Imagine I have this array

```
 $records = array(
array(
    'id' => 2135,
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
),
array(
    'id' => 3245,
    'first_name' => 'Sally',
    'last_name' => 'Smith',
),
array(
    'id' => 5342,
    'first_name' => 'Jane',
    'last_name' => 'Jones',
),
array(
    'id' => 5623,
    'first_name' => 'Peter',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
)
);
```

I tried this

```
 array_keys($records)
```

But it does not return this

```
Array
(
    [0] => id
    [1] => first_name
    [2] => last_name
)
```

I want to know the name of the columns and how many of them to have the possibility to change the query on the database and have the table with the right amount of columns right away

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming in your array you have at least one row, all rows have the same columns, you could do:

```
<?php
    $numColumns = count($records[0]);
    $numRows = count($records);
    $columnsNames = array_keys($records[0]);
?>
```

This is because you have an array of arrays, so it is correct to use array_keys(), you just need to do it on one (in this case the first) of the arrays contained in $records

Comment: Whats the purpose of the count?

Comment: `count` returns the amount of entries in an array, be numeration or associative

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand MazzCris's answer, so I'll answer the question as I understand it.

Access the first subarray, then extract the keys.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/JLYF9))

```
$keys = array_keys($records[0]);
var_export($keys);
echo "\n";
echo "Number of columns: " , count($keys);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'id',
  1 => 'first_name',
  2 => 'last_name',
)
Number of columns: 3
```

Comment: Does anyone have the courage to justify these downvotes?